# Why can I not cast Signature to my own class?

Tags: java, casting

So I have implemented a signature class, ultimately deriving from SignatureSpi.  In my class, I have added a public method to utilize some logic written higher up the class hierarchy. There are a few levels of abstraction; that is not important, what is important is that, one of the classes farther down provides method A() which I want to call from my class.

So, I have:

```
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance(sigAlg, "provider");
sig.initSign(privKey);
sig.update(data);
byte[] signature = sig.sign();
byte[] plainSig = ((MySigProviderClass)(SignatureSpi)sig).ExtDecodeSignature(signature);
```

All looks good in the IDE (intellij).

But instead, I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.security.Signature$Delegate cannot be cast to com.company.my.provider.signature.MySigProviderClass` when I try to run it. Why?

I know I can extract the code from A() and place it elsewhere... I was hoping to simply have a quick n dirty hack to access it.

Comment: Because `sig` is nor an instance of `com.company.my.provider.signature.MySigProviderClass` neither a subclass instance?

Comment: Well why do you think that object *would* be an instance of `MySigProviderClass`?

Comment: Because, when I step into the code (say, from sign(), I end up in my class?  Obviously, there's some nuance of the service provider interface that I'm not getting...

Comment: Updated code to include how sig is assigned... it references MySigProviderClass  from the provider.jar... so it seems reasonable to me that I should be able to reference it via cast, no?

Comment: `Signature` extends `SignatureSpi`, not the other way around.  Therefore, if you have created a class that extends the latter, then it is not a subclass of the former.  Note, too, these comments from `Signature`'s Javadoc: "Note that this class is abstract and extends from SignatureSpi for historical reasons. Application developers should only take notice of the methods defined in this Signature class; all the methods in the superclass are intended for cryptographic service providers who wish to supply their own implementations of digital signature algorithms. "

Comment: But, sig is holding an instance of the class I defined, so how, other than through methods defined in the SPI, can I reference my own methods in MySigProviderClass... or can I not do that at all?

Comment: `sig` may be *holding* an instance of your SPI class, but that is very different from *being* an instance of that class.  You cannot invoke methods on your SPI implementation via `sig`, except inasmuch as the `Signature` methods delegate to methods of the SPI object.  You certainly cannot cast `sig` to your SPI class, and even if you could, that's not the same as obtaining its internal SPI object.

Comment: Okay, I am starting to see how it's all working now, well, at least from the high level view, anyway.  I imagine, then, that there is no way I can utilize methods in an intermediate class without defining a static method .. which may work to just utilize methods, but doesn't help when I want to use those methods on a particular instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [getInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html#getInstance%28java.lang.String%29) method doesn't return your signature class directly, it returns a proxy object which will eventually delegate all calls to your implementation:

> Returns a Signature object that implements the specified signature algorithm. [...] A new Signature object encapsulating the SignatureSpi implementation from the first Provider that supports the specified algorithm is returned.

Comment: That makes sense now.  So much to read and so many little nuances.